# New Orchard User Crashes Website Each time new User Logs in

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

Can anyone advise me on this one please? I've got a fully functional Orchard Site with content and all is well. However, so far i've only EVER used the DEFAULT ADMIN account. I've added modules and everything is complete.

Now I want to add a user that's just for EDITING and ADDING content and cannot say, add modules etc. I create a new user and approve them, then I try to LOG in as them and the Site crashes. Then I cannot get back in. I had to Recycle the Application pool to get back in as ADMIN. Anyone seen this before?

```
[ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists[Orchard.Roles.Models.PermissionRecord#27]]
   NHibernate.Impl.DefaultEntityNotFoundDelegate.HandleEntityNotFound(String entityName, Object id) +56
   NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.CheckTargetState() +48
   NHibernate.Proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.Initialize() +89
   NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.LazyInitializer.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) +123
   Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +81
   PermissionRecordProxy1b0b6ea8f5864e2c9211eba674e34740.get_Name() +84
   Orchard.Roles.Services.RoleService.GetPermissionsForRole(Int32 id) +133
   Orchard.Roles.Services.RoleService.GetPermissionsForRoleByNameInner(String name) +37
   Orchard.Roles.Services.<>c__DisplayClasse.<GetPermissionsForRoleByName>b__d(AcquireContext`1 ctx) +26
   Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.CreateEntry(TKey k, Func`2 acquire) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\Cache.cs:57
   Orchard.Caching.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Get>b__0(TKey k) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\Cache.cs:19
   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func`2 addValueFactory, Func`3 updateValueFactory) +125
   Orchard.Caching.Cache`2.Get(TKey key, Func`2 acquire) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\Cache.cs:17
   Orchard.Caching.DefaultCacheManager.Get(TKey key, Func`2 acquire) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Caching\DefaultCacheManager.cs:33
   Orchard.Roles.Services.RoleService.GetPermissionsForRoleByName(String name) +100
   Orchard.Roles.Services.RolesBasedAuthorizationService.TryCheckAccess(Permission permission, IUser user, IContent content) +561
   Orchard.Security.Authorizer.Authorize(Permission permission, IContent content, LocalizedString message) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Security\Authorizer.cs:72
   Orchard.Security.Authorizer.Authorize(Permission permission) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Security\Authorizer.cs:60
   Orchard.Security.SecurityFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Security\SecurityFilter.cs:24
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +103
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +329
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +31
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.HttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) in c:\Build\Orchard\src\Orchard\Mvc\Routes\ShellRoute.cs:147
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970061
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

Comment: Seems like it has to do with that user's roles. Does he have any? Is it possible that he has a role that disappeared?

Comment: That was spot on, by editing the existing Roles some were crashing. I just deleted the ones that were. Then renamed the working ones to suit, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it has to do with that user's roles. Does he have any? Is it possible that he has a role that disappeared? Try to delete the faulty roles.